# Run configuration with clear app storage doesn't clear storage

Tags: android-studio

Just updated Android Studio to the latest version (Iguana 2023.2.1). When running an app configuration with (Clear app storage before deployment) the app storage is not cleared.
Full configuration:
[Run configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq1bX.png)

I tried creating another run configuration but results are the same.

Comment: Hey Syper, I have the same problem since I updated to Iguana. Did you solved it ?

Comment: No, but using a 30 API android version seems to be working as intended. I think the problem is related to the latest api levels